# Using Icons in div class without using navigation or icon bar

Tags: html, css, frontend, bootstrap-4, web-frontend

I want to add upto 6 icons in a div bar in Bootstrap as shown in the below wireframe, I have already made it in an icon bar class but my supervisor has prohibited me to do so, so I cant use any of the navigation bars or icon bars. What will be the best way to do it? Also How to keep it seperate from the below div?

[The wireframe of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YkBv.jpg)

Following is my html code:

```
<nav class="navbar ">
<div class="icon-bar">
  <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"> </i> </a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"> </i> </a> 
 <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"> </i> </a> 
 <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"> </i> </a> 
 <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"> </i> </a> 
</div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color: green;"></div> <br> <br>
```

Comment: Where is your code? Stackoverflow is not a coding service. Please provide a **working** example in your question to allow us to awnser it better.

Comment: Not sure what your supervisor has prohibited to do ? And what is the requirement exactly. Nothing is clear.

Comment: My supervisor has prohibited me not to use the icon bar as well as the navigation bar instead use a simplified div. I have now updated the working but prohibited solution of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple copy and paste

```
<style>
 .icons_div {
      margin: 0px auto;
      width: max-content;
  }
  .icon{
    margin : 0px auto;
    width: 15px;
    display: initial;
  }
  .fa {
    padding: 0px 10px;
  }
</style>
```

```
<div class="icons_div">
    <div class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    <div class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    <div class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    <div class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    <div class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    <div class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did the job thanks.. But is there any way to do it by using bootstrap classes not neccesarily CSS?